# Aguardar preenchimento da variavel

Tags: javascript

Olá, tenho a seguinte array

["lucas", "pedro" ,"joao"]

Preciso enviar um pedido com XMLHttpRequest para cada nome, depois salvar a resposta em json dos 3 em um objeto e chamar uma outra função, o problema é que não sei como faço para que a execução aguarde até que as 3 var estiverem preenchidas, e só depois chame a function

Ouvir falar que Promises pode me ajudar, alguém tem uma soluçao?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, promises neste caso é útil. Podes fazer isso usando Promise.all que espera pelas Promise que vão buscar os dados:

```js
function getNome(nome) {
  const url = 'https://httpbin.org/get?nome=' + nome;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      else reject(xhr.status);
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

const nomes = ["lucas", "pedro", "joao"];
Promise.all(nomes.map(getNome)).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```