# Fazer código que usa Promises funcionar também em navegadores antigos

Tags: javascript, promises

Recentemente fiz essa pergunta:

[Aguardar preenchimento da variavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253810/aguardar-preenchimento-da-variavel)

O moderador Sergio me ajudou com a questão, mas ainda estou com problemas com a compatibilidade com navegadores antigos. Existe uma forma de realizar isso sem o uso de Promises e que rode em navegadores mais antigos?

Segue o código do exemplo:

```js
function getNome(nome) {
  const url = 'https://httpbin.org/get?nome=' + nome;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
      else reject(xhr.status);
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}

const nomes = ["lucas", "pedro", "joao"];
Promise.all(nomes.map(getNome)).then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

O que eu quero é percorrer uma array, e realizar uma requisição em cada nome e salvando a resposta em um objeto, enquanto isso o código vai continuando rodando e fazendo outras tarefas, quando todas as respostas estiverem em um objeto o código aciona uma outra função.

Comment: Se o problema é o suporte a Promises, por que não usa um [polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill)? Ou, melhor ainda, por que não usa um [transpilador de Javascript moderno para Javascript antigo](https://babeljs.io/), assim não precisa ficar fazendo código feio-- o transpilador faz para você e você não precisa nem ver.

Comment: Ainda nao tenho como usar o babel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com callbacks assim:

```js
function getNome(nome, cb) {
  const url = 'https://httpbin.org/get?nome=' + nome;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) cb(null, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    else cb(xhr.status);
  };
  xhr.send();
}

function processador(arr, done) {
  var respostas = [];
  var total = arr.length;
  arr.forEach(function(el, i) {
    getNome(el, function(err, res) {
      if (err) done(err);
      respostas[i] = res;
      total--;
      if (total == 0) done(null, respostas);
    })
  });
}

const nomes = ["lucas", "pedro", "joao"];
processador(nomes, function(err, res) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(res);
});
```

A ideia é gerir as respostas com funções ([callbacks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/129)) e ir juntando à array resposta o que vai sendo recebido, no index certo usando o `i` no `.forEach`